# How to group a dataset into top-K plus others in Vega-Lite

Tags: bar-chart, vega-lite

I would like to create a stacked graph bar similar to
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/stacked_bar_weather.html

My dataset contains

- dates   - x     (temporal, 1 year with a granularity of 1 day)
- hits    - y     (quantitative)
- country - color (nominal)

The number of countries is significant but I only want to show the top 5 and
group the rest under the label OTHER. I want to select the top 5 over the
complete time period of one year (not the top 5 per each individual day).

I am able to select the top-5 with the following top-5 transform:

```
  "transform" : [
    {
      "aggregate" : [ {"op": "sum", "field": "hit", "as": "hit_sum_by_country"} ],
      "groupby" : ["country"]
    },
    {
      "window": [ {"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"} ],
      "sort": [ {"field": "hit_sum_by_country", "order": "descending"} ]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.rank < 5 ? datum.country : 'others'", "as" : "top_country"
    }
  ],
```

This, however, munges my original data.

So it looks like I would need to do the top-5 transform on the side
and then somehow inject `"top_country"` to the original dataset.
Is this possible? Or should I be doing this outside vega (i.e.
in javascript or server-side)

UPDATE: an example in the [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAJgAMN-tYCM9h4ox0DqAJyelUNg1lMACcATwsAVQBlEABfBRM1c3QbO0dnVxh3NE8HX39A0IsAKQAFWPiVRIsU62d0pUzMDwBmHxA-AOCw9ABhADlyhLNq21q0xwys1AAWNo6C7pBwgGlByuHk0bqJhqnp3Pb8rosAQXC10ySrLfGXXaa0A-nj9AAxACULqs3Upx23B6oZp5TqFdAAIU+cSGVxq2zuAI8cyOYJAAEkACpfDbXX71RHZEELU5QiqXEZ42yTQGeYGHUGLKLY2E3P6WalIp4oxalZkUsZsjloVpEl4gfp8n4C+zs+4eWai1ErSW46VUuVofaKxZnFVw8aygmoLkMiwfPWsmVCoHaiyQi2Uw2NDwm4noTEOtVOqbI03oE6kmH87bNa3NOnPJXRaHrFmU0Ma1CWV1i3kx8lSkPWyzTW29Abp76qrOJ6a5+luparQs4-V-BNGrUVsW6mtxtUN52PPMgPoAGU9JaNEe5dsDseD407UxTqPBAFFB1Prb7KwGl39pmGR36ltGyUW6-Yt4nLJYe2mD7XLdYT0bkz2JW3J5vrQAOcuRxY9AASG+P1pNl+pznM+mbjHeXbGj2-b-reYY9vaYHFhB1qzosC5wZBPo9uuMQALpxCAyBBAA1hYTBIEErhwLIfjKDQshkGgoAAB4sSAmA0AgcDhLIdAWOSSgAGY0HAgjKIJVRKJgIQ4FcbBBAxsg6K4XGYIIVwACJVER3SgLJ8kWAAjgwSCBHQag0KQriieJknoF2Ml0JpFg-lkRF+IIikcXZEkWMBMlyVcshsAgjGqc5GlXD0o4xPFQA). The chart is hard to read because of the number of countries that are color-coded. I would like to select top-5 and then group (sum) all others under one label/color **OTHER**.

UPDATE-2 another [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAJgAMN-tYCM9h4ox0DqAJyelUNg1lMACcATwsAVQBlEABfBRM1c3QbO0dnVxh3NE8HX39A0IsAKQAFWPiVRIsU62d0pUzMDwBmHxA-AOCw9ABhADlyhLNq21q0xwys1AAWNo6C7pBwgGlByuHk0bqJhqnp3Pb8rosAQXC10ySrLfGXXaa0A-nj9AAxACULqs3Upx23B6oZp5TqFdAAIU+cSGVxq2zuAI83jmRzBIAAkgAVL4ba6-eqI7IghanKEVS4jfG2SaAzzAw6gxZRHGwm5-Sw0pFPVGLUosyljdmctCtYkvED9fk-QX2Dn3DyzMVolZSvEy6nytD7JWLM6quHjOWEoHNbmMiwffVs2XCoE6iyQq1Uo2NDxmknoLFO9UuqYo83oE5kmEC7bNW3NenPZXRaHrVlU8Oa1CWd3ivlxinSsO2yzTe29AaZ75qnPJ6b5hkeparYu4g1-JPG7VV8V6usJ9VN11oMRiNNovoAGW9ZeNUZ5DuD8dD427UwHi3BAFFR3PbQ5-dWg2u-tMIxOA0tY+SSw37Pvk5ZLAWQBnT-XrdZL8bU7fJR3Z3vbQAOSvRplawfTtthfHsZkXU5zk-bNxjAhdb2HXcLwjW9HRg0s4NzN9WzRFdkOfW0tzbacs0wv4xAPW9mQw89rEoq8b1w3kylop8GNfSDCwIjjwL-aigJDWCKNtFsAKgniN0Qkc2KpXipkPat0OAr97HkwEmPEiFV1k9V1Lda9iLRHcYgAXTiEBgiQWQIAAMzYIIECMUBJDYGhZCQMgyCCPgNmMEA2BwCwIAYJylFsmg4EEZQLB7JQkA8AEAH0QoQJKmBCJLxLMpRvP8HAMqMZiQHMioAHd3OUNgyucgKgvQIJqqS2RQqYOAglcBKLCCayAGtYlMpQZCCTBaoiqKYvQRoUtC9LMvEpQHOUdqLGW6A4FkZR3LIAbcsahgCu6QwZ1K0AoB0KAGEEEtTFCygetkXqAAIAB4AF4nrEJ6AH4ntuhBKAAp7UCegByAB5eh2tBzrEswQKssnHKQGQIJ+vQJgkA6pQNr8LbZB2zQQAADzQUBMBoBA4HCWQ6FWqpwsi6L6eGJRMBCHAriW9ydFcCnMEEK4ABEqgs7pyY5q4AEcGGs-m1BoUhXHG5mpqyeKvJ8ihcVSvm6EFiwAAksgsvxBAcsmQBVybLIRhbLMlixZDYBAecEPWBauHpJyGhzRtQY6Hv60qAqCZaOqJ63ur6zrNd8q5dd9kbVv0KANvxnaYizoA) linked from the comment

Comment: This question needs more information: What do you mean by "select the top 5 over the year"? Do you mean select the 5 countries with the maximum value over the full year? Or the maximum of the sum of values for the full year? And when you say "group the other countries", how do you want the values to be aggregated? max? mean? sum? Including a simple example dataset (say 4 countries over 5 days, where the goal is to split into "top 2" and "other") would make this easier to answer.

Comment: Select the 5 countries with the maximum of the sum over the full year. (I do this in the transform shown in the question.) And then show the remaining countries under label _Others_. So if you go to the linked chart (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/stacked_bar_weather.html) it shows: sun, fog, drizzle, rain, snow. In my case that would be: US, China, Japan, UK, Australia, _Others_, where _Others_  is the sum of other countries (Brazil, Argentina, Italy, France, etc.)

Comment: @jakedvp - I have updated the question with a link to the vega editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want to do with the following transform:

```json
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "hits", "as": "hit_sum_by_country"}],
      "groupby": ["country"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "hit_sum_by_country", "order": "descending"}],
      "groupby": ["date"]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.rank <= 5 ? datum.country : 'Other'", "as": "country"}
  ],
```

Note: this pre-supposes that each country has an entry at each date; if not, you'll also have to add an imputation transform before the window transform.

Here's the result ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAJgAMN-tYCM9h4ox0DqAJyelUNg1lMACcATwsAVQBlEABfBRM1c3QbO0dnVxh3NE8HX39A0IsAKQAFWPiVRIsU62d0pUzMDwBmHxA-AOCw9ABhADlyhLNq21q0xwys1AAWNo6C7pBwgGlByuHk0bqJhqnp3Pb8rosAQXC10ySrLfGXXaa0A-nj9AAxACULqs3Upx23B6oZp5TqFdAAIU+cSGVxq2zuAI8cyOYJAAEkACpfDbXX71RHZEELU5QiqXEZ42yTQGeYGHUGLKLY2E3P6WalIp4oxalZkUsZsjloVpEl4gfp8n4C+zs+4eWai1ErSW46VUuVofaKxZnFVw8aygmoLkMiwfPWsmVCoHaiyQi2Uw2NDwm4noTEOtVOqbI03oE6kmH87bNa3NOnPJXRaHrFmU0Ma1CWV1i3kx8lSkPWyzTW29Abp76qrOJ6a5+luparQs4-V-BNGrUVsW6mtxtUN52PPMgPoAGU9JaNEe5dsDseD407UxTqPBAFFB1Prb7KwGl39pmGR36ltGyUW6-Yt4nLJYe2mD7XLdYT0bkz2JW3J5vrQAOcuRxnVq-t7Z3rsZlnHVzmfTNxgAmce37DdjzDHt7TA4sIOtYC7UXJCj1vFce3XGIAF04hAYIkFkCAADM2CCBAjFASQ2BoWQkDIMggj4DZjBANgcAsCAGBopRyJoOBBGUCwuyUJAPABAB9PiEBkpgQhkr9YnwpRWP8HAlKMZtCkIioAHdGOUNhDNoriePQIIzJk2R+KYOAglcKSLCCUiAGs1KUGQgkwCyhJEsT0EaOT+MU5TVKUKjlCcixYugOBZGURiyG8kBNIYbTukMCcDNAKAdCgBhBCLUx+ModzZA8gACAAeABeGqxBqgB+GryoQSgvxq1AaoAcgAeXoJz+pc6TVIIpRkCCLz0CYJBnKUJK-BS2Q0s0EAAA80FATAaAQOBwlkOh4qqQThNEs7hiUTAQhwK4YsYnRXH2zBBCuAARKoiO6Pb7quABHBhSLetQaFIVxAqukKskkli2IoHF5NeugPosAAJLIiL8QQqN2kBoeCvSwlugGLFkNgEGewRUfeq4elHHyqP81BcqqryDK4oJYuczaibczyXIR9irhR5m-Pi-QoCSta0piBWgA)):

[image]

Edit: here's what the transform might look like if you need to impute missing values:

```json
  "transform": [
    {"impute": "hits", "key": "country", "value": 0, "groupby": ["date"]},
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "sum", "field": "hits", "as": "hit_sum_by_country"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["country"]
    },
    {
      "window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "hit_sum_by_country", "order": "descending"}],
      "groupby": ["date"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "datum.rank <= 5 ? datum.country : 'Other'",
      "as": "top_country"
    }
  ],
```

The result looks something like this, using the data from your updated example ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoVZjhoQAJgAMN-tYCM9h4ox0DqAJyelUNg1lMACcATwsAVQBlEABfBRM1c3QbO0dnVxh3NE8HX39A0IsAKQAFWPiVRIsU62d0pUzMDwBmHxA-AOCw9ABhADlyhLNq21q0xwys1AAWNo6C7pBwgGlByuHk0bqJhqnp3Pb8rosAQXC10ySrLfGXXaa0A-nj9AAxACULqs3Upx23B6oZp5TqFdAAIU+cSGVxq2zuAI83jmRzBIAAkgAVL4ba6-eqI7IghanKEVS4jfG2SaAzzAw6gxZRHGwm5-Sw0pFPVGLUosyljdmctCtYkvED9fk-QX2Dn3DyzMVolZSvEy6nytD7JWLM6quHjOWEoHNbmMiwffVs2XCoE6iyQq1Uo2NDxmknoLFO9UuqYo83oE5kmEC7bNW3NenPZXRaHrVlU8Oa1CWd3ivlxinSsO2yzTe29AaZ75qnPJ6b5hkeparYu4g1-JPG7VV8V6usJ9VN11oMRiNNovoAGW9ZeNUZ5DuD8dD427UwHi3BAFFR3PbQ5-dWg2u-tMIxOA0tY+SSw37Pvk5ZLAWQBnT-XrdZL8bU7fJR3Z3vbQAOSvRplawfTtthfHsZkXU5zk-bNxjAhdb2HXcLwjW9HRg0s4NzN9WzRFdkOfW0tzbacs0wv4xAPW9mQw89rEoq8b1w3kylop8GNfSDCwIjjwL-aigJDWCKNtFsAKgniN0Qkc2KpXipkPat0OAr97HkwEmPEiFV1k9V1Lda9iLRHcYgAXTiEBgiQWQIAAMzYIIECMUAaAQHAGFxHslAAazgRZxKUbRdCSawlDIIJ-BwJhukMGdzIqSQ2BoWQkDIcK+A2YwQDYHALAgBgnKUWyaDgQRlAsLyQCQDwAQAfXyhBaui2rxLMsKIoYKKYuYkB4tAAB3ZLlDYfrnOy3L0Ai-ratkAqmDgIJXGqiwgms7zYlMpQZCCTAxuK0ryvQRp6oKpqQhayclAc5QFosG7oDgWRlGSsgNvayLoqMOK4ygHQoAYQQS1MArKFW2RvIAAgAHgAXghsQIYAfgh4GEEoACIdQCGAHIAHl6AW7GlpqzAcou802pAZAgnW9AmCQRalEevxntkV7NBAAAPNBQEwVy4HCWQ6DuqoipKsqReGJRMBCHArmu5KdFcPnMEEK4ABEqgs7pedlq4AEcGGslW1BoUhXH2iWjqyJRUvSihcQa5W6DViwAAksgsvxBAcnmQEtw7LLJgLLL1ixZDYBBFcEZ3VauHpLpAbbdo5nK8oKi3xcDsH1piCzrtujmA5WtalrSoIMquJ2toclOVH0KBHtZ1685iIA)):

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. this is close but not quite there yet.

I want to select the top five countries globally (i.e. without grouping by date) and then for each date show a bar char with the global top five + others.  In other words - the **Country** legend will ever list at most 5+1 entries (whereas in the example in UPDATE-2 I got it to show 8). I thought omitting `"groupby" : ["date"]` in the `window` transform will do the trick but that reduces the number of colors down to 2 (?) Would that be related to the missing imputation transform you mention?

Comment: That's exactly what this solution does, so long as each country has an entry at each date. As mentioned in my answer, if that is not the case you'll have to use an impute transform to address it.

Comment: The reason omitting `"groupby": ["date"]` in the `"window"` transform breaks the computation is that there is a duplicate `rank` entry at every date for every country, so omitting the groupby leads you to find the top country multiple times.

Comment: I added an impute transform to my answer; see edits above.

Comment: Yes - I get it now. Thanks!